What transformation to adjust empirical data variance 'smoothly'?
Let's assume we have empirical data for an outdated process that generated it.
We have reason to believe the process of today is similar (e.g. same distribution) but with a different variance.
General question: in such a case, how to adjust outdated empirical data to better reflect nowadays? i.e. what general transformation to apply on data would allow creating pseudo-data providing up to date variance (that we assume here having)?
If instead of the "variance" we had the "mean", then a translation would do the trick.
For the variance, timing sample by a scalar would provide a variance timed by the square of this scalar, but in this case the whole empirical sample is adjusted by the same amount.  I was more thinking to something more "elastic", which would not modify an observation if close to the mean, but quite a lot if it's far from it (something squared root I guess).

Why can't you collect new data from the new process? That way, you will have real data, which tells you how it really behaves.

Even if you can't collect data and are just trying to understand the new process, it matters how the variance changed.  What insight do you have into the cause of this change?

@whuber we have the new value of var and we can assume that obs near to the mean moved just a little and obs far from it moved substantially more.
Objective here is to find a proxy more relevant than a pure rescale to reflect that, even if conscious that is limited

"Just a little" and "substantially more" cover a lot of ground! Letting the (common) mean be $\mu,$ you seem to be saying there is some convex function $f$ with minimum at $0$ and the new process $Y$ in terms of the original process $X$ is $Y_t=\mu+f(X_t-\mu).$ You are asking us to opine about $f$ but, so far, we haven't any other information about it.

I think you answer covers pretty much what I was looking for.
f can then be handle on a case by case basis I guess. Thanks!
